# Special Character file upload WP Filebase Wordpress

Tags: character-encoding, wordpress, urlencode, sanitize

I try to apply the function to sanitize file downloaded from the plugin WP Filebase
In the `functions.php` file of my theme I included this

```
function make_san_filename($filename) {
    $info = pathinfo($filename);
    $ext  = empty($info['extension']) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $name = str_replace($ext, '', $filename);
    return sanitize_title(strtolower($name)) . $ext;
}

add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'make_san_filename', 10);
```

The function works perfectly with the files manager Wordpress, URLs of my files are clear, but the function does not work for the downloaded files with WP Filebase, so I can not replace the special characters in my URLs as : e + ® to Â ...

Any idea or alternative ?

Comment: You have to look for any hook in WP Filebase plugin to know how they sanitizing the filenames. Maybe they are not filtering through `sanitize_file_name` filter.

Comment: I tried to look into the WPFibelase files, but I have not seen anything about sanitize, and I do not understand where to add this feature ...

Comment: You must have to dig into WP Filebase Plugin or contact the author to know more about how file naming is working.